# Gröbner basis and dg structures

Tags: groebner-basis, differential-graded-algebras

Gröbner basis is typically defined for ideals of polynomial rings over a field and there are several generalizations/extensions of this notion for non-commutative structures or differential algebras.
I would like to ask if the notion of Gröbner basis has been defined for dg-modules or dg-algebras or commutative dga as well.

Comment: I think that this question covers the specific case of finitely generated commutative DGA: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152519/is-the-ideal-membership-problem-solvable-for-differential-ideals-is-there-a-goo